# how to insert an array in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, postman

I have modal, inside the modal there is a form when i click the submit button it will do this.

jquery code:

```js
  $('#add-new-content-form').on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //I want to add this block dates to the data
    let blockdates = $("#block-dates").val();

    let title = $("#card-title").val();
    let catalogId = $("#catalog").val();
    let categoryId = $("#category").val();
    let subcategoryId = $('#subcategory').val();
    let why = $("#why").val();
    let description = $('#card-description').val();
    let cancellationPolicy = $('#cancellation-policy').val();
    let displayPrice = $('#display-price').val();
    let displayDiscounted = $('#discounted-price').val();
    let displayMaxPax = $('#display-maxpax').val();
    let data = {
      "blockDates":[
                 { 
            "description": "national araw ng mga puso day!",
            "notAvailableDate": "2019-02-14 10:00:00"
              },
              { 
            "description": "chinese new year!",
            "notAvailableDate": "2019-02-25 10:00:00"
              }
               ],
      "title": title,
      "catalogId": catalogId,
      "categoryId": categoryId,
      "subcategoryId": subcategoryId,
      "why": why,
      "description": description,
      "cancellationPolicy": cancellationPolicy,
      "displayPrice": displayPrice,
      "displayDiscounted": displayDiscounted,
      "displayMaxPax": displayMaxPax
    };
     let content = ajax("api/unitContents", JSON.stringify(data), "POST");
    // window.location.replace("/category");
  });
```

Now, in the postman there is something just like this:

```
{   
"blockDates":[ 
    { 
        "description": "national araw ng mga puso day!",
        "notAvailableDate": "2019-02-14 10:00:00"
    },
    { 
        "description": "chinese new year!",
        "notAvailableDate": "2019-02-25 10:00:00"
    }
],
"location":{
    "identifier":"UBZ190asas11",
    "name": "abulalas,purok 4",
    "address" : "abulalas1 hagonoy bulacan",
    "lat" : 12141.00,
    "lng" : 123251.00
},
"units": 2,
"title": "sample unit content",
"catalogId": 6,
"categoryId": 22,
"subcategoryId": 13,
"contentOptions": [ 
     {
        "name":"bannana boat",
        "maxPax":8,
        "isAvailableDayTime":[
            9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,
            33,34,35,36,37,39,38,39,40,
            56,57,58,59,60,62,63,64,65,
            80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,
            104,105,106,107,108,110,111,112,113,
            128,129,130,131,132,134,135,136,137,
            152,153,154,155,156,158,159,160,161
        ],
        "inventoryNeededSet":[
            {
            "inventoryId": 1,
            "count":1
            },
            {
            "inventoryId": 1,
            "count":2
            }
        ],
        "paxPrices": [
            {
                "count": 5,
                "pricePerPax": 200,
                "totalPrice": 1000,
                "fee": 100
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "pricePerPax": 200,
                "totalPrice": 200,
                "fee": 10
            }
        ]
     },
     {
        "name":"bannana with island tour",
        "maxPax":10,
        "isAvailableDayTime":[
            9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,
            33,34,35,36,37,39,38,39,40,
            56,57,58,59,60,62,63,64,65,
            80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,
            104,105,106,107,108,110,111,112,113,
            128,129,130,131,132,134,135,136,137,
            152,153,154,155,156,158,159,160,161
        ],
        "inventoryNeededSet":[
            {
            "inventoryId": 1,
            "count":2
            },
            {
            "inventoryId": 1,
            "count":2
            }
        ],
        "paxPrices": [
            {
                "count": 5,
                "pricePerPax": 200,
                "totalPrice": 1000,
                "fee": 100
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "pricePerPax": 200,
                "totalPrice": 200,
                "fee": 10
            }
        ]
     }

],
"photos": [
    "https://samplephoto1.com",
    "https://samplephoto2.com",
    "https://samplephoto3.com"
],
"videos": [
    "https://samplevid1.com",
    "https://samplevid2.com",
    "https://samplevid3.com"
],
"why": "sample why",
"description": "sample desc",
"cancellationPolicy":"cancellationPolicy",
"displayPrice": 300,
"displayDiscounted": 250,
"displayMaxPax": 2
```

}

the thing is, I want to save the blockdate, what is the syntax of inserting the blockdates?

=======================UPDATED======================

Comment: your code is not completed... where comes `blockdates` from ? from `JSON.stringify(data)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this before stringifying the data variable:

`data.blockdates = $("#block-dates").val();`

Answer (score 0):

To execute your code `jQuery` is needed. Try after inserting `<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>` before your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `let blockdates = $("#block-dates").val();`

You can append `blockdates` into `data` like this

`data['blockdates']=blockdates;`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to keep the elements in an object first. You can then add them to the array.

```
blockDates= [];
var description = $("#card-description").val();
var notAvailableDate = $("##block-dates").val();

var blockdate = {description, notAvailableDate};

blockDates.push(blockdate);

in this way => let content = ajax("api/unitContents", JSON.stringify(data, blockDates), "POST");
```

or

```
    let data = {
          "title": title,
          "catalogId": catalogId,
          "categoryId": categoryId,
          "subcategoryId": subcategoryId,
          "why": why,
          "cancellationPolicy": cancellationPolicy,
          "displayPrice": displayPrice,
          "displayDiscounted": displayDiscounted,
          "displayMaxPax": displayMaxPax,
          "blockDates": blockDates 
        };

in this way => `let content = ajax("api/unitContents", JSON.stringify(data), "POST");`
```